# Directional buttons (arrows) in datagrid easyui

Tags: datagrid, jquery-easyui

How do I use arrow buttons on keyboard to move around datagrid cells?
I need examples.

Comment: What are you asking???

Comment: How do I use the directional buttons(arrows) in a datagrid (easyui)?

Comment: The question says `As I can use datagrid....`